# how to clean ex smokers lungs

Tags: lungs

I am ex smoker. I smoked for decade  and quit smoking. here on [this link]http://hangover-cure.co.uk/smokers-and-ex-smokers/) I have found a solution for cleansing the lung. is it safe and a possibke way for cleansing the lungs? or any other better ideas ?

Comment: This is absolute garbage! How could anything taken into one's digestive system cleanse the lungs? In order to do so, it would somehow have to transport the toxins into the bloodstream where they could be removed by the kidneys and liver.

Comment: @BillOertell Your comment fails the "be nice" test.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I thought calling this article "garbage" was being charitable. Please note, I was not calling the OP garbage.

Answer (score 3):

The cited article offers no mechanisms of action, no data to corroborate the claims, and no research (not even observational). It merely makes unsubstantiated claims and offers them as fact. As I pointed out in my comment, I can think of no mechanism by which any of the cited regimens could produce the desired effect.
That said, the only thing I know of that can cleanse the lungs is time.